# Скрипт на Unity для переключение модели

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, vuforia

Я совсем недавно начал изучать Unity и Vuforia и у меня возник вопрос. Можно ли создать две сцены: меню и AR. В меню сцене много кнопок с разными надписями, к которым будет привязан, допустим, номер или название 3D модели. Дальше при нажатие на кнопку в сцене, где у нас AR в ImageTarget менять модель. Если да, то какой скрипт нужно использовать(я разобрался как делать переключение между сценами, тут не знаю как)

Comment: Можно. Но перед тем как лезть в проэкты юнити желательно разобраться с азами программирования в принципе.

Comment: @Andrew, ммм, я с ними хорошо знаком

Comment: Вы можете использовать статические переменные для сообщения между сценами.

Comment: @МаксимФисман спасибо

Comment: Спасибо значит, что помогло (дам подробный ответ)?

Comment: @МаксимФисман попробую разобраться, но можете и объяснить, если несложно

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать в скрипте статическую переменную, в которой будете хранить модель.
При выборе модели - присваиваете ее переменной, при загрузке новой сцены берете значение этой переменной. Так как она статическая, то не будет меняться и будет одна, даже если экземпляров класса будет несколько.

```
public static GameObject model;
```

Comment: @nafagJi Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, примите его, нажав галочку. Это значит, что ответ получен, а вопрос закрыт. Здесь вы можете подробнее узнать, что стоит делать с ответами на вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers